# How to convert one data type to another

Tags: vb.net

I am a very novice VB.NET programmer. How do I convert one type to another?

```
Dim a as String="2"
Dim b as Integer='what?
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7708838/how-do-i-convert-from-a-string-to-an-integer-in-visual-basic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to convert a string to an integer.

1. You know the string contains a numeric:

   ```
   Dim b as Integer = Integer.Parse(a)
   ```

   If it is not a valid integer or contains non numerals, it can crash.  Other value types (Decimal, Double) have the same method.
2. Pretty much the same:

   ```
   Dim b as Integer= Convert.ToInt32(b)
   ```
3. You dont know if the string is clean or not.  For instance this would be used to convert a value from a text box, where the user types "cat" as their age:

   ```
   If Integer.TryParse(a, b) Then ...
   ```

The big difference here is that the return is a Boolean (True or False) telling you whether the parsing went ok.  If not (False), tell the user to enter again; else (True) the second param will be the converted value.  `Date`, `Double`, `Decimal` etc all have a `TryParse` method.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21782533/1070452) provides a more detailed explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Many of the "primitive" data types have several parsing methods that can construct from a string representation.

Check the `Parse` and `TryParse` shared methods of `Integer`.

Comment: What about from any type? Like the `Convert` class in C#.

Comment: @EdwardKarak - `Convert` most certainly doesn't handle **any** type. It is coded for specific, common, usages. There is no way to simply convert between any two unknown types.

Comment: @EdwardKarak The System.Convert class comes from the framework, not from C#, so it is the same in VB.NET.