# Converting DataTypes for Option Strict

Tags: vb.net

I was just wondering how to correctly

1. Convert string to date
2. Convert integer to short
3. Convert string to integer
4. Convert string to double

correctly without using any Ctypes of any sort. I turned on Option Strict and now all these errors popped up so I'm trying to fix them :)

Comment: Take a look at `Date.Parse`, `Integer.Parse` and `Double.Parse` for starters

Comment: Converting an `Integer` to a `Short` *could* be lossy, so you have to perform an explicit conversion (`CShort(123)`, for example)

Comment: Why do you say *without CType*?  What if `CType` *is* the correct way?

Comment: @Steven Doggart Well for our assignment the instructor just says `Ctype` is very messy and not necessary. I'll use it if I have to though

Comment: I'm sorry, but I respectfully disagree.  `CType` and `DirectCast` should not be considered messy or unnecessary.  They are often required when you turn `Option Strict On`.  They are certainly optional when you turn `Option Strict Off`, but I would argue that doing *that* often leads to messy and sloppy code.  As @RowlandShaw said, if you are converting an `Integer` to a `Short` with `Option Strict On`, calling `CType` (or `CShort`, in this case) *is* the best way to do it.  You could also use the `Convert` class, I suppose, but I would prefer `CShort` over that, personally.

Comment: Ask the instructor for the proper way to convert/cast the `sender` argument in an event when you need to use sender.  Then show him it is liberally and appropriately used on MSDN examples, then again in the MS NET reference source. the conversions listed can be done without Ctype, but it is neither messy nor unneeded.

Comment: So just out of curiosity, is oh say, `CShort()` and `Short.parse()` the same thing?

Comment: The parse methods should be used any time you are converting from a string to some other type.  Although the `CType` methods will technically work, in some cases, like that, it's confusing, in my opinion.  I would just use the `CType` methods when you are *casting* the value, use the `Convert` class for converting values that go beyond a simple cast, and then use `Parse` or `ParseExact` when converting from a string to anything else.

Comment: @StevenDoggart I would suggest using `DirectCast` when simply casting a value (it's more strict; it's also faster, but that does not matter most of the time), if possible. Otherwise I totally agree.

Comment: @DominicKexel Agreed, `DirectCast` is better and more clear when that is what you want to do.  But for something line `Integer` to `Short`, `DirectCast` will not work.  Even when it does work, sometimes that's not what you want (such as when the `CType` operator is overloaded).  However, even though converting an `Integer` to a `Short` with `DirectCast` is impossible, I would still call it "casting", since that's what it would be called in other languages like C#.

Answer (score 2):

NET provides several ways to check, test and convert data.

**TryParse**

This is perhaps the most bulletproof way to convert.  It is ideal for validating user input:

```
Dim n As Int32
If Int32.TryParse(TextBox.Text, n) Then
    ' work with n
Else
    ' error handling: TextBox.Text cannot convert to int
End If
```

All the core datatypes support it (`Int64`, `Decimal`, `Date` etc).  It is different from others: it does not return the converted value, but a `Boolean` indicating whether the source string could be converted to a variable.

**Parse**

```
Dim d as Double = Double.Parse(strVar)
```

This is ok to use when your code created `strVar` and you know it contains numerals and not punctuation etc.  `Parse` and `TryParse` both allow you to parse data from other cultures by providing a `FormatProvider` and other options:

```
Dim strDec = "$ 123.45"
Dim decVal As Decimal = Decimal.Parse("$123.45", NumberStyles.Currency)
```

Other methods will choke on the "$", the style argument allows it.

**Convert.ToInt32 / Convert.ToInteger**

This one has many, many overloads:

```
Dim intV As Int32 = Convert.ToInt32(aString)
Dim dblV As Double = Convert.ToDouble(aString)
Dim lngV As Int64 = Convert.ToInt64(aString)
```

The `Convert.Toxxx` methods are slightly less specialized than the ones above.  They allow culture conversions, but they assume a **direct conversion** is possible. That is, "123" will convert to integer, but not "123.45" and it wont know anything thing like currency formats.

So, use this when you know the value can convert, perhaps because you converted the value to string.  These also work to unbox objects from a database `DataReader`:

```
myDT = Convert.ToDateTime(rdr("BirthDate"))
myV = Convert.ToInt32(rdr("FooValue"))
```

Provided the data is actually stored as those types and "boxed" as Object for the `DBDataReader`, `Convert` will work fine. (Note that DBDataReaders can return typed data directly: `n = rdr.GetInt32(1)` but you cannot use the column name, just the ordinal position).

**CInt, CSng...etc**

`CInt` is similar to `Convert.ToInteger`, but according to MSDN optimized for use in VB.  For instance:

```
a = Convert.ToInt32("123.50")     ' exception due to decimal point
a = CInt("123.50")                ' a = 124
```

Confusing?  Yes, but once you get a handle on them, you can use the method which best fits the situation.  There is no way to specify a culture for `CInt`, `CDec` etc.

**Val**

Don't use `Val`. Ever.  It is a very generic function which returns a `Double`.  Using it can result in all sorts of undesirable Type conversions:

```
Dim n = Val(tbSmallValue.Text)
```

`n` is created as a Double so if the textbox was "5", then `n` = `5.0`.  When `n` is used where an integer is expected (such as inserting into a database) errors can happen.  The result varies greatly:

```
dd = Val("123.4")          ' = 123.4
dd = Val("$123.45")        ' = 0.0
dd = Val("123abc")         ' = 123.0
```

---

**NB** `CInt` and `Convert.ToInt32` implement "Banker's Rounding" where `.50` fractions are rounded to the *nearest even number*.  `123.50` and `124.50` both round/convert to `124`.