# Execute code block certain number of times

Tags: vb.net

So i want to perform some code N times. N is textbox's value (e.g: 12).

I have no idea how to accomplish this, but something like this is on my mind:

```
For Each i as 1 in textbox1.text
  'some code
Next
```

or

```
dim num1 as integer = 0
While num1 < textbox1.text
  'some code
  num1 += 1
Next
```

Those were just some ideas that were on my mind when i though about this question, none of above is tested nor tried to code.

Any ideas?

Comment: `for n as int32 = 0 to N-1`...  `while` is more appropriate when you dont know how many times to loop

Comment: and turn on option explicit

Comment: no, `Option Strict` a TextBox, does not contain numbers.  Ever.

Answer (score 3):

First and foremost, turn on `Option Strict`.  This will save you time in the long run by converting possible runtime errors into compiler errors.  At the top of the code file:

```
Option Strict On
```

It can also be set for the entire project:
**Project Properties** -> **Compile Tab** -> **Option Strict** selector: **On**

You can also make it the default for all new projects via:
**Tools** -> **Options** -> **Projects and Solutions** -> **VB Defaults**

#### What it Does

`TextBox.Text` always contains text (hence the clever names).  `"12"` is just a string and is not the same as `12`.  So, before you can use it, you need to convert from string to integer.  **Note**: If you want to restrict user input to numbers consider using a `NumericUpDown`.

There are several ways to convert, but considering that the data comes from a user, we have to allow that they may enter `"I like pie"` instead of numerals.  So, we want to use the safest method which in this case is `Integer.TryParse`:

```
' declare int var to hold the result
Dim LoopCount As Integer
If Integer.TryParse(TextBox132.Text, LoopCount) Then
    ' success!  LoopCOunt contains the integer value of the Text control

    For n As Integer = 0 To LoopCount - 1
       ' some code to do something
    Next
Else
    ' failed - scold the user with a MessageBox
End if
```

The comments in the code explain, but first you declare an integer variable to hold the converted value.  `Integer.TryParse` is a function which will return `True/False`.  If it succeeds, your variable will hold the integer value.

See **[Converting DataTypes for Option Strict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21780619/making-changes-with-option-strict-on)** for other convert methods and cases where they are appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

This might work, I haven't tried:

```
Dim repeat_times as Integer = 0
    Do Until repeat_times = 10 'times you want to repeat
    repeat_times = repeat_times + 1
    Console.WriteLine("Hello World") 'or anything you want
    Loop
```

Answer (score -1):

`For n As Int32 = 0 To TextBox1.text - 1` was an answer for my question.

Comment: A textbox never contains numbers.  That wont compile under `Option Strict `which is essential for serious or even just good programming.  You need to try to convert the contents of the TextBox to an integer before you use it in the loop.