# Invalid Cast Expectation Was Unhanded (when checking the contents of a text box)

Tags: vb.net

This code is from a subroutine that checks if a text box entry fits the criteria specified (an integer between 1 and 100).

The first IF statement should check if it is not a numerical entry. If it is not numerical then the contents of the text box should be set blank so that a number can be entered.

The second IF statement should check if the number is larger than 100. If it is then the contents of the text box should be set blank so that an appropriate number can be entered.

The Third IF statement should check if the number is smaller than 1. If it is then the contents of the text box should be set blank so that an appropriate number can be entered.

Finally the contents of the box should be set as the variable.

I initially programmed the first IF statement on its own and it worked. But upon adding the others my program would crash when I typed anything into the text box and the error was as stated in my title. I have looked at multiple solutions and have found nothing for almost 2 days that fixed the problem.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
Public Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles NumQTextBoxInput.TextChanged
            'Check if input is numeric
            If Not IsNumeric(NumQTextBoxInput.Text) Then NumQTextBoxInput.Text = ""
            If (NumQTextBoxInput.Text > 100) Then
                NumQTextBoxInput.Text = ""
            End If
            If (NumQTextBoxInput.Text < 1) Then
                NumQTextBoxInput.Text = ""
            End If
            ArchwayComputingExamCreator.GlobalVariables.NumOfQuestions = NumQTextBoxInput.Text
            'Setting the variable to the contense

        End Sub
```

Comment: Turn on Option Strict.  Textboxes do not contain numbers, only text. so `If (NumQTextBoxInput.Text > 100) Then` is a nonsense test.  If the control contains "Ziggy" is that more than or less than 100?

Comment: [This answer is entirely applicable](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42459667/1070452) except for the loop part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should always use the appropriate parse function when accepting text for numbers.

```
Public Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles NumQTextBoxInput.TextChanged

    Dim Value as integer
    If Not Integer.TryParse(NumQTextBoxInput.text, Value) OrElse Value < 1 OrElse Value > 100 Then NumQTextBoxInput.Text = ""

    ... no idea if the archway bit is really what you wanted so left that out .... 

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

In this operation:

```
If Not IsNumeric(NumQTextBoxInput.Text) Then NumQTextBoxInput.Text = ""
```

Any time the input is not numeric, you set it to a value which is still *not numeric*.  So any numeric comparison will fail:

```
If (NumQTextBoxInput.Text > 100)
```

Maybe you meant to set the value to some numeric default?:

```
If Not IsNumeric(NumQTextBoxInput.Text) Then NumQTextBoxInput.Text = "0"
```

Or just exit the method entirely when it's not numeric?:

```
If Not IsNumeric(NumQTextBoxInput.Text) Then
    NumQTextBoxInput.Text = ""
    Return
End If
```

Or perhaps something else?  However you modify your logic, the point is that you can't perform numeric comparisons on non-numeric strings.